# Strange behavior of Perl regex in cronjob

Tags: bash, perl, cron

I have files like:

```
[grundbild]
geo40=AdnQywADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAt8AAAIVAAAAAAAAAAAAAALfAAACFQAAAAAAAAAAB4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAt8AAAIV
[MainWindow]
geo40=AdnQywADAAAAAAAXAAAAEQAABrwAAAPwAAAAGAAAADAAAAa7AAAD7wAAAAAAAAAAB4AAAAAYAAAAMAAABrsAAAPv
dockPos40=AAAA/wAAAAD9AAAAAQAAAAAAAACyAAADcfwCAAAAA/sAAAAOAGsAZQB5AGwAYQBiAHMBAAAAOQAAAW4AAAAtAP////sAAAASAHMAdABhAHIAdABtAGUAbgB1AQAAAa0AAAFtAAAAWQD////7AAAAEgBoAGUAbABwAF8AZABvAGMAawEAAAMgAAAAigAAAIoA////AAAF7AAAA3EAAAAEAAAABAAAAAgAAAAI/AAAAAEAAAACAAAABAAAABIAcwBoAG8AcgB0AGMAdQB0AHMBAAAAAP////8AAAAAAAAAAAAAABYAbQBpAG4AaQBkAGUAcwBrAHQAbwBwAQAAADH/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAASAGgAZQBsAHAAZgB1AG4AYwBzAQAAAKT/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAG8AYgBpAQAAAR7/////AAAAAAAAAAA=
```

Because the key "geo40" causes many problems, I want to delete all lines starting with "geo40=" out of the concerning files.

I tried

```
find /conf/ -type f -name "geometry.*.pas" -exec perl -pi -e 's/^geo40=.*$\\n//' {} ';'
```

and it works fine. I get files like

```
[grundbild]
[MainWindow]
dockPos40=AAAA/wAAAAD9AAAAAQAAAAAAAACyAAADcfwCAAAAA/sAAAAOAGsAZQB5AGwAYQBiAHMBAAAAOQAAAW4AAAAtAP////sAAAASAHMAdABhAHIAdABtAGUAbgB1AQAAAa0AAAFtAAAAWQD////7AAAAEgBoAGUAbABwAF8AZABvAGMAawEAAAMgAAAAigAAAIoA////AAAF7AAAA3EAAAAEAAAABAAAAAgAAAAI/AAAAAEAAAACAAAABAAAABIAcwBoAG8AcgB0AGMAdQB0AHMBAAAAAP////8AAAAAAAAAAAAAABYAbQBpAG4AaQBkAGUAcwBrAHQAbwBwAQAAADH/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAASAGgAZQBsAHAAZgB1AG4AYwBzAQAAAKT/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAG8AYgBpAQAAAR7/////AAAAAAAAAAA=
```

But if I run it via cronjob

```
0 5 * * * find /conf/ -type f -name "geometry.*.pas" -exec perl -pi.cronbak -e 's/^geo40=.*$\\n//' {} ';'
```

I get

```
[grundbild]
QywADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAt8AAAIVAAAAAAAAAAAAAALfAAACFQAAAAAAAAAAB4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAt8AAAIV
[MainWindow]
QywADAAAAAAAXAAAAEQAABrwAAAPwAAAAGAAAADAAAAa7AAAD7wAAAAAAAAAAB4AAAAAYAAAAMAAABrsAAAPv
dockPos40=AAAA/wAAAAD9AAAAAQAAAAAAAACyAAADcfwCAAAAA/sAAAAOAGsAZQB5AGwAYQBiAHMBAAAAOQAAAW4AAAAtAP////sAAAASAHMAdABhAHIAdABtAGUAbgB1AQAAAa0AAAFtAAAAWQD////7AAAAEgBoAGUAbABwAF8AZABvAGMAawEAAAMgAAAAigAAAIoA////AAAF7AAAA3EAAAAEAAAABAAAAAgAAAAI/AAAAAEAAAACAAAABAAAABIAcwBoAG8AcgB0AGMAdQB0AHMBAAAAAP////8AAAAAAAAAAAAAABYAbQBpAG4AaQBkAGUAcwBrAHQAbwBwAQAAADH/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAASAGgAZQBsAHAAZgB1AG4AYwBzAQAAAKT/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAG8AYgBpAQAAAR7/////AAAAAAAAAAA=
```

Only the key "geo40=" is gone. The 2nd part of the regex `.*$\\n` seems to be ignored.

(On the command line, it works if I act as user or as root, it works by using bash or sh)

Comment: While I don't see on the spot the reason for this behaviour, I find the regex weird. What is the `$\\n` supposed to do? The [meaning of a `$` (without presence of a m-modifier)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre) is: _Match the end of the string (or before newline at the end of the string)_. In your context, the string is the complete line. Therefore, I would drop the \\n.

Comment: I'd just do the whole thing in perl instead of trying to combine it and `find`. The `File::Find` module is handy for such things, or `File::Find::Rule`.

Comment: @user1934428 That's all wrong. 1) We want to remove the LF, so the `\n` needs to stay. 2) Your describing `(?:$)\n`, in which the `$` is superfluous but harmless. 3) `$\\n` is actually an interpolation of the `$\ ` variable followed by a LF. `$\ ` contains an empty string in the program in question, so it works, but it should be removed.

Comment: @user1934428 - I didn't had in mind, that Perl replaces variables in the regex... embarrassing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more straightforward approach is to use Perl to filter lines instead of performing a substitution on all lines.  Print all lines unless they start with the string `geo40=`:

```
0 5 * * * find /conf/ -type f -name "geometry.*.pas" -exec perl -ni.cronbak -e 'print unless /^geo40=/' {} ';'
```

It's a lot less punctuation that you don't have to worry about escaping and being interpolated.

Note that it uses [`perl -n`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-n) instead of `perl -p`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I suspect there may be some quoting of the quoted quotes going on, as you're layering a `perl`-ish complexity of `$\\n` escapes in single-ticks in a `find` inside `cron`. I tend to try and remove layers when possible, and quotes when it helps.

Also, you do you, but `s///` feels like the wrong tool here. You want to delete the line, not edit it. Maybe the semantics matter.

[toolic's `print unless`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76120131/8656552) is better, as it's doing what you actually want, but even then it's using a negative ("unless").

Personally, I'd just use `sed` for this.

```
find /conf/ -type f -name "geometry.*.pas" -exec sed -i '/^geo40=/d' {} ';'
```

That's clearly ***delete** lines that match this pattern*.

Likewise, I get that it's common, but not really a fan of `find` for things like this. I get that it lets you specify details like `-type f`, so sometimes it's the perfect tool, but even then I personally like `xargs` better than `-exec`. YMMV.

*Personally*, I prefer `globstar` if I don't *need* things like `-type f`, unless the list is so long it becomes problematic for your `limits`.

```
shopt -s globstar; sed -i '/^geo40=/d' /conf/**/geometry.*.pas
```

That's one call to `sed`, rather than a `find` (and maybe an `xargs`) *plus* a `sed` per file. Be aware that you might need to wrap that in a script with a `bash` shebang...or maybe just

```
0 5 * * * bash -c 'shopt -s globstar; sed -i '/^geo40=/d' /conf/**/geometry.*.pas'
```

As I said before, YMMV.

Comment: If you use `-exec sed ... {} +` instead of `-exec sed ... {} ';'`, it's just one call to sed too. And unlike globstar, it avoid command line length limitations.

Comment: Huh. I thought it'd `-exec` a `sed` for each relevant file.

Comment: With `;`, yes. With `+`, no.